# how to filter data while retrieving from mongoDB hosted on mlab

Tags: android, mongodb, rest

[REST API code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UbLFsmJPwtYnVmSWdFVjhUSEE)[complete displayfitactivity code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UbLFsmJPwtNmpMRlJPU252ME5IZWdUNXZNSE85b1cyTmtV)1. this is my code to retrieve data from mlab and displaying it in android app.
2. i have used RESTful api to connect it with mlab ref->youtube.com/watch?v=pI9FSrP2Fyo&t=954s
3. i have 4 columns in my collection 
 "bookname": "spcc",
    "author": "john",
    "price": 1234,
    "stock": 5, //ref mlab
i want to filter data like by author name or by price > 50 and price <200 etc.
i will get data(filtering condition) from user in android app.so how i write in this method to get only those documents which satisfies user filtering conditions ?//sorry if its too basic question

```
     private String getData(String urlPath) throws IOException {
        //  n.setText("GET Data");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =null;

        try {
            //Initialize and config request, then connect to server
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Read data response from server
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                result.append(line).append("\n"); }
          }
         catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }   
       return result.toString();
    }
```

and this string result is passed to postExecute for displaying data

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        List<Books> data=new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray obj ;
        try {
            obj = new JSONArray(result);
            //obj = new JSONObject(result);
            cN = new String[obj.length()];

            Books[] bookData = new Books[obj.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobj = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                // Books bookData = new Books();
                String N1;
                bookData[i] = new Books();
                bookData[i].id = jsonobj.getString("_id");
                bookData[i].bookName = jsonobj.getString("bookname");
                bookData[i].authorName = jsonobj.getString("author");
                bookData[i].price = Integer.parseInt(jsonobj.getString("price"));
                bookData[i].stock = Integer.parseInt(jsonobj.getString("stock"));
                data.add(bookData[i]);
                if (i == obj.length() - 1) {
                    n.setText("total row = " + obj.length());
                }
```

Comment: what are the conditions to be met?

Comment: like display all books written by xyz author or display books costing between 50-100
filtering condition will be given by user as input.

Comment: I think you need only fetch to database after input recieved from user.Use the conditions and fetch db

Comment: thats what idk.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pI9FSrP2Fyo&t=954s with help of this video i created Rest api to connect with mongodb on mlab and to implement CRUD operations. i dont know where and what to write to filter documents specifying user conditions

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UbLFsmJPwtYnVmSWdFVjhUSEE
RESTAPI code